# dll used by CLR at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clr

I've got a C# application which refers to a .NET DLL.
If this DLL is present both in my application's `bin` directory and GAC, then 
which one will be picked up by the CLR at runtime? If GAC has the latest version, would that version be used instead of the one present in `bin`?

And how do I force the CLR to always use the one in my `bin` instead of GAC?

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The CLR checks the global assembly cache, codebases specified in configuration files, and 
>   then checks the application's directory and subdirectories.

So, does that mean it looks into GAC first?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You force the CLR to *not* use a copy of an assembly in the GAC by not having it in the GAC.  Simple to do by renaming the DLL or by changing its [AssemblyVersion] before referencing it in your project.  Skipping this invokes nasty runtime exceptions, otherwise known as DLL Hell.

Comment: Thanks.And could you please answer my other question: If GAC has the latest version, would that version be used instead of the one present in bin?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with "latest".  Your program asks for a specific assembly name and [AssemblyVersion] as obtained from the reference assembly.  Only an **exact** match on that version is considered.  Any other matching strategy would invoke DLL Hell.